# rewrite Urls using htacess

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting

I have a website as a side hobby.

I purchase a custom script from a developer. That script is designed to be run on the main domain. like www.example.com

This is because of the script using require_once and include_path function to call files within the script. For example /functions.php or /admin.php

So if I configure it on the main domain it works but on the subdomain, it gives 403 Forbidden error because of the nonexistence of URLs.

I mean for subdomain the directories inside it should be changed to 
subdomain.example.com/functions.php or subdomain.example.com/admin.php.

Here is the problem there are more than 100+ pages and it would be quite hard to change it one by one for me.

I am looking if I can do it using .htacess rewrite module.

Is it possible if on page load the directories inside the files can be altered?

Comment: `require` and `include` go on the filesystem path rather than the URL so it shouldn't make any odds on whether it's on the main domain or a sub-domain - unless you've got filesystem paths like `/var/www/html/subdomain.example.com/` ? Normally you'd just reference the server's docroot (`$_SERVER['DOCROOT']`) or something similar.

Comment: htaccess doesn't have anything to do with `includes` or `require`. We know literally nothing about your code or your set up so it's quite impossible for us to be able to help. It's also very unclear if it is a file path or url issue. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks it is fixed now :D